# Maximum and Minimum of Totally Ordered Compact Sets

Tags: general-topology

Let T be a totally ordered compact set. Does this always imply that a maximum and a minimum element of T exist under this total order?

And if not, what about the special case where:

- T is a closed and bounded interval of the real line (ergo compact) with the usual total order $\leq$ of the reals

Comment: Do you mean that $T$ is a compact subset of a linearly ordered space with the order topology? And are you asking whether $T$ has a maximimum and minimum element, or are you asking about continuous functions defined on $T$?

Comment: Brian, I am referring to the general case where T is a compact set, and you are given a total order on the elements of this set.  But, just in case this is not true in the general case, I ask whether it is true for the special case of the real line and the usual ordering of the reals.

Comment: Unless the linear order is related to the topology, there is no reason to expect it to have any topological effect in general. And since you didn’t answer the second question, I still don’t know what you’re asking even in the real case, I’m afraid.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the existence of a minimum and maximum *element* of $T$.

Comment: yes, exactly, I will edit to clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $T$ is a compact set in a linearly ordered space $X$ with its order topology, then $T$ has both a minimum and a maximum element.

To see this, merely note that if $T$ has no largest element, then $\{(\leftarrow,x):x\in T\}$ is an open cover of $T$ with no finite subcover, and if $T$ has no smallest element, then $\{(x,\to):x\in T\}$ is an open cover of $T$ with no finite subcover.

In particular, this is true if $X$ is the real line with the usual topology, since that topology is the one induced by the usual linear order on $\Bbb R$. If the linear order is not related to the topology, however, nothing can be said: it is always possible to put a linear order on an infinite set in such a way that the set has neither a least nor a greatest element.

Comment: Thanks Brian! That solves my question. I will up-vote once I register.

Comment: @user19902: You’re welcome!

Comment: Could you also explain the use of \leftarrow and \rightarrow in the above intervals?

Comment: @user19902: That’s another standard notation for the open rays to left and right; you may be more familiar with the notation $(-\infty,x)$ and $(x,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

First you need some compatibility conditions the reason is the following. Take $T:=[0,1]$ the segment in $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology, it is well known that there exists a bijection $f$ between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

If you define $\leq_{[0,1]}$ to be the total order induce by $f$ i.e. :

$$a\leq_{[0,1]}b\Leftrightarrow f(a)\leq f(b) $$

Then, somehow $T$ is  a totally ordered compact set (i.e. some compact set with a total order) but won't have maximal element nor minimal element...

That is you must have a condition relating both that is (I think) for every $a\in T$ you must have :

$$\{t\in T|a\leq t\}\text{ and } \{t\in T|t\leq a\}\text{ are closed.} $$

i.e. :

$$\{t\in T|t< a\}\text{ and } \{t\in T|a<t\}\text{ are open.} $$

Now if $T$ has no maximal element then for all $t\in T$ you can find $t'\in T$ with $t<t'$ (the order is total) finally :

$$\bigcup_{a\in A}\{t\in T|t< a\}=T $$

But then you can take a finite cover out of it let's say for $a_1,...,a_k$ but then taking the maximal element of those $k$ elements (let's say it is $a_k$) then you have :

$$T=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{t\in T|t< a\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^k\{t\in T|t< a_i\}=\{t\in T|t< a_k\} $$

Finally you have that $a_k\notin T$ which is a contradiction. Of course, the same applies to the minimal element.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is the fact that f is not finite the source of the problem? But if I can always find t'>t, and since T is bounded, how is that possible?